# ASP.net mvc how to comment out html code in page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there an easy way to comment out a loop which renders some html and has inline html without deleting anything? I am copying and pasting some code from another project to rebuild a new public front end from a working internal backend.

Below is an example of a sitation in which it would be nice...in asp.net MVC 2

```
        <% 
       List<VehicleBodyTypeListItem> lstBodyTypes = (List<VehicleBodyTypeListItem>)ViewData["ddBodyType"];
       foreach (VehicleBodyTypeListItem bodyType in lstBodyTypes)
   {
      %>
      <a href="<%= Url.Action( "Search", new { BodyTypeID=bodyType.BodyTypeID, BodyType= Url.Encode( Html.WebLinkify( bodyType.BodyType))}) + (string)ViewData["httpCriteria"] %>">
        <%= Html.Encode( String.Format( "{0} ({1})", bodyType.BodyType, bodyType.Count.ToString()))  %>        </a>
        <br />
      <%
   }
   %>
```

I have not completed the method that populates this list yet, and have about 5 more like it further down the page.

Comment: AFAIK /* ... */ should work. You may have to apply some single-line comment delims after each of your <%= tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut is, if you select the section you want commented out is: CTRL + K + C will comment out code. CTRL + K + U will uncomment the code.

Answer (score 7):

Comment a block of code by enclosing it in @* and *@

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean adding comments to the code. If so you just need to add //. Like here:

```
            <% 
       List<VehicleBodyTypeListItem> lstBodyTypes = (List<VehicleBodyTypeListItem>)ViewData["ddBodyType"];
       foreach (VehicleBodyTypeListItem bodyType in lstBodyTypes) // Here there's a comment
   {
      %>
      <a href="<%= Url.Action( "Search", new { BodyTypeID=bodyType.BodyTypeID, BodyType= Url.Encode( Html.WebLinkify( bodyType.BodyType))}) + (string)ViewData["httpCriteria"] %>">
        <%= Html.Encode( String.Format( "{0} ({1})", bodyType.BodyType, bodyType.Count.ToString()))  %>        </a>
        <br />
      <%
   }
   %>
```